# Uploading story to user story field without creating new story object ,but rather add to already upload stories of that user

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

Okay I have been stack in trying to have user create stories and add to their already uploaded stories in the backend database, but my current challenge is each time that a user uploads a story it doesn't add the story to the already existing field for that user, but rather create a new story object for that user! Is there a way that i could let users upload their new stories to add to already uploaded stories of that user but not create a new story object ?
My view for creating stories.

```
def create_story(request):
    # add new story of user if user has none create new or add to already existing one.
    orig_story = Story.objects.prefetch_related('storyimage_set').get(pk=request.user.id)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = StoryImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=orig_story)
        videos =request.FILES.getlist('video')
        images = request.FILES.getlist('image')
        title = request.POST['title']
        story_data = Story(user=request.user,title=title)
        story_data.save()
        if form.is_valid():
            data = form.save(commit=False)
            for image in images:
                data = StoryImage(post=story_data,user=request.user,images=image)
                data.save()
        return redirect('feed:feed')
      
    return render(request,"story/create_story.html")
```

Model

```
class Story(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,related_name="like")
    views = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,related_name="story_views")
    slug = models.SlugField()
   
    objects = StoryManager()
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super(Story, self).save(*args, **kwargs)    

    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('glam:stories',kwargs={'slug':self.slug})
    
class StoryImage(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Story, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    images = models.FileField(upload_to='StoryImages/%Y/%m/%d/',blank=True)
    video = models.FileField(upload_to='StorVideos/%Y/%m/%d/',blank=True)
```

Form

```
class StoryImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = StoryImage
        fields = ['images']
        widget= forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple':True})
```

Comment: Could you please post your forms and models code?

Comment: @B.Anup I just did!

Comment: In-order to save the new story in the database, new row has to be added in 'Story' model.  It is not like, new row is created for the user, but new row is created in 'Story' model for the new story object and it will be in relation with the user. So existing functionality is the expected, whenver user uploads new story, new row is created in 'Story' model.